# giving error "Too many arguments, expected arguments "command"." while installing magento 2.4

Tags: installation, magento2.4, cli

gatting error **"Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".**" while installing magento2.4 through command line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add double quote on each value? Like below

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento2/"  --db-host="127.0.0.1" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="vinay" --db-password="pd9@wzmnhum31" --admin-firstname="vinay" --admin-lastname="sirige" --admin-email="vinaysirige@gmail.com" --admin-user="vinay" --admin-password="pd9@wzmnhum31"
```

Thanks